# Retrieving data from an HTML Class Element using VBScript

Tags: html, vbscript

I created a basic VBScript to change the temperature on my Honeywell WIFI thermostat, which uses a web interface.
I can get to the site, login, change the temp and submit the change.
Now I want to retrieve the Temperate the thermostat is set to.  I know where to find the info in the Source document of IE, but I do not know how to call it.
Here is the HTML element that contains what I need.

```html
<div id="NonAutoHeatSetpt" style="">
  <div class="SetPtContainer">
    <div class="CurrSetptHdr">Set To</div>
    <div class="CurrentSetpt"><div class="DisplayValue">22.0</div><span class="NoBold">&deg;</span></div>
  </div>

<div class="SetPtButtons" style="">
    <div id="NonAutoModeHeatUpBtn" class="UpBtn unselectable"> </div>
    <div id="NonAutoModeHeatDownBtn" class="DownBtn unselectable"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to retrieve the 22.0, so that I can create a loop that will keep decreasing the temperature until the target temperature (which will be determined in my script) is reached.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
Sub WaitForLoad 'Sub to wait for browser to load
 Do While IE.Busy
   WScript.Sleep 10
 Loop   
End Sub

On Error Resume Next

 Dim IE
 Dim SetTo1
 Dim SetTo2

 Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 IE.Visible = True 
 IE.navigate "https://mytotalconnectcomfort.com/portal/"
 WaitForLoad

 IE.Document.All.Item("UserName").Value = "myemail@yahoo.ca"
 IE.Document.All.Item("Password").Value = "MyPassword"
 IE.Document.All.Item("submit").Click
 WaitForLoad 

 IE.Document.All.Item("NonAutoModeHeatDownBtn").Click 'Clicks on the decrease temp btn
 IE.Document.All.Item("SubmitBtn").Click 'Submit changes to thermostat
 WaitForLoad

 Set SetTo1 = IE.Document.getElementByID("NonAutoHeatSetpt")
 Set SetTo2 = SetTo1.getElementsByClassName("DisplayValue")
```

SetTo1 comes back as an HTML Element et SetTo2 comes back as an HTML Collection.

Based on the HTML code above, I believe that the 22.0 that I am looking for is stored in the "DisplayValue" HTML Collection.  How can I use it?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the size of the collection, use 'length'

```
Msgbox SetTo2.length 'will print how many items are present in the collection
```

To get the value (index starts from 0)

```
Msgbox SetTo2.Item(0).InnerText 'will print 22.0
```